# PHP and html uploader

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my code but it is not about and error.

1) when I hit to refresh I still see previously echoing variables.

2)when I choose a file, it is supposed to transfer from temp_name into the 'uploads/' but it doesn't + it doesn't throw 'uploaded' message.

3) when I don't choose a file and submit it,  it should say 'please choose a file.

can you explain me **HOW** to solve my issues and **WHY** are these things happening?

```
   <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $size=$_FILES['file']['size'].'kb'."<br>";
    $name=$_FILES['file']['name']."<br>";
    $type=$_FILES['file']['type']."<br>";
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."<br>";
    if (isset($name))
    {
        if(!empty($name))
        {
            $location='uploads/';
        if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$name))
            {
                echo 'UPLOADED';
            } 
          echo 'OK.';
        }else 
            {
            echo 'please choose a file.';
            }
    }


    }

    ?>

    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <br>
    <input type ="file" name="file">
     <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="Submit">

    </form> 

    <?php


    echo 'File size: '.$size;
    echo 'File name: '.$name;
    echo 'File type: '.$type;
    //echo 'File temporary place: '.$tmp_name;
    ?>
```

PS: this is a screenshot from page after just hit the refresh button

[image]I

Comment: You're simply assuming uploads can never fail. Bad decision. there's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason... And you're embedding HTML into your file names. `<br>` should not be part of the filename...  `/tmp/foobar23423423<br>` does not exist, therefore there's nothing to move.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['file'])){...}` in addition to ^

Comment: ...while dropping `if(!empty($name))` you want to check if the file's field itself isn't empty. That name can always be changed.

Comment: Use the $_FILES error:    $_FILES["file"]["error"] .  Code meanings can be seen here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php.  You should probably not use isset($name) either, check the length of $name.  $name is always set as you tell to be equal to "file name" and "<br/>" so will always have at least <br/> in it - put the <br/> tags in the display area at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, using the file error value.  Values will be 0 to 8 for different issues:  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"]==0){ //success so far

        $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
        $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
        $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];     
        $location='uploads/';
        try{
             $result =  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$name); // this will throw warnings though!
             if($result){
                 echo 'UPLOADED AND MOVED';
             }else{
                    echo "Unable to move the file";
             }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Sorry there was a problem ".$e.getMessage();
        }
    }else{ //some sort of problem
        echo "There was a problem with the upload (error code: ".$_FILES["file"]["error"].")";
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"]==4 ){ // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
            echo "<br/> Please choose a file to upload";
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that your uploads folder exists and the permissions are set correctly.  Display the correct errors may help.

Comment: very nice suggestion thank you ... since I am improving myself on php it would help alot... another thing as I described after i refresh previously "echo"ed are appearing again ... why do they appear how can I stop them to disappear when I refresh page... I searched for it what I saw, "ob_end_clean();" however that also prevents when I submit the uploading one  @jonholland

Comment: A couple of things here - if you refresh the page after submission, you will resend the form data again (you will usually be asked to confirm this).

Secondly, in your script your are echoing out $size, $name and $type regardless as to whether anything has been posted.  These have not been declared in advance and will throw warnings, which I assume you have switched off.  I recommend putting the warnings on as these will guide you when you are making non critical mistakes and will help you become a better coder.

Comment: Move your echos into the if logic bit and not at the bottom, where they will always try and show,